# Python while loop breaks due to float64 iterator

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a while loop like;

```
j = 0
while j < len(THR_1):
    if THR_1[j] != 0:
        total_firing_count = total_firing_count + 1
        if THR_1[j] >= 2:
            firing_count_longer_2s = firing_count_longer_2s + 1
            firing_longer_2s.append(THR_1[j])
        j += (THR_1[j]/0.05) - 1
    j += 1
```

and I get an error like;

KeyError: 3.0000000000000004

This value belongs to my iterator which is float64.

[image]

How can I fix this? Many thanks in advance...

Comment: You can always try rounding your iterator, but why is it a float64 anyway?

Comment: Note that if `THR_1[j]` is an int, then `THR_1[j] * 20` is also an int, but `THR_1[j] / 0.05` is a float.

Comment: Why do you need to add `(THR_1[j]/0.05) - 1` to `j`? Looks like there might be a better way of achieving whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: @Stuart I had to do this because I am searching in a dataset that has duplicate values. For example I have 5 times 0.25 which indicates a sequence continues 0.25 seconds with 0.05 second time steps. Thats why I had to eliminate those duplicate values in my query.

Thanks for other comments by the way. I think I have to round it.

Comment: A code sample, which can't be run as is, is of limited value. I suspect, that this is the usual float problem, read here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generator to remove the duplicates and zeroes, to get the data into a more convenient form, before analyzing it.

```
def find_nonzero_values(sequence, step):
    sequence = iter(sequence)
    for item in sequence:
        if item:
            yield item
            for _ in range(round(item / step) - 1):  # skip ahead
                next(sequence)
            
THR_1 = [2] * 40 + [0] + [1] * 20 + [0] + [.25] * 5   # example data
sequence = list(find_nonzero_values(THR_1, .05))   # [2, 1, 0.25]

# It is now much easier to filter and count items in the data
total_firing_count = len(sequence)  # 3
firing_longer_2s = [item for item in sequence if item >= 2]  # [2]
firing_count_longer_2s = len(firing_longer_2s)   # 1
```